# Stop animating UIActivityIndicatorView when UIImageView image has finished loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I want to display the spinning activity view over a UIImageView and stop and hide the activity view once the image has finished loading and is displayed. The image is a large photograph taken from the assets-library.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //set photo
    UIImageView *Photo = _photo;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:project.photo];
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
        if (iref) {
            self.photo.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage] scale:[rep scale] orientation:0];

        }
             } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                 NSLog(@"Couldn't load asset %@ => %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);



             }];

    [_ImageLoader stopAnimating];
}
```

This, however, does not work as the activity view is constantly spinning.

Comment: where are you calling [_ImageLoader startAnimating] ?

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_ImageLoader startAnimating];
}

Comment: They have different names... Isn't that your problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistype, I've amended now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner is always animated because

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

is called after

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

So basically your telling the spinner to animate after telling it to stop.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Heliem, seems obvious looking at it now!

Answer (score 1):

Helium is right. You want to move the cal to [_ImageLoader stopAnimating] inside the result block, or you end up stopping the animation before it even started.